# Safari can't login to my FTP server

Tags: ftp, safari, ftp-server

I've implemented an FTP server (in Qt/C++), and all clients can login, but Safari tries with anonymous login, and then gives up.

This is the control connection log:

```
connection from "192.168.0.102" 
reply 220 "Welcome to QFtpServer." 
command "USER anonymous" 
reply 331 "User name OK, need password." 
command "PASS cfnetwork@apple.com" 
reply 530 "User name or password was incorrect."
```

At that point other FTP clients will pop-up a dialog asking their user to supply a user-name and password, but Safari just says "You don't have permission to open this page".

The only way to open is to specify the username and password in the URL.

Should I change how the FTP server responds?

**Edit:** I just tested that Safari can't login to Filezilla Server as well, and it always asks for password, even for non-existant usernames, just like my server.

Comment: Do you allow anonymous access in the server? If you do, why reply with okay for the username and fail for the password? If you don't allow anonymous logins, reply with an error already on the `USER` command.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg See my edit, I tested and the behavior of Filezilla server is the same. It waits for the password even when you supply it with a non-existent username. If a popular file server does it, I'm assuming the behavior is correct. Safari fails with it, too.